# Google app engine push notification response shows success 1 but app doesn't receive notification

Tags: android, python, google-app-engine, google-cloud-messaging

I am using the google app engine URL:'https://android.googleapis.com/gcm/send' and I receive the success key to be 1 as the response. But my app never receives the notification. What could be the reason for this?

My response body:

```
{
 u'failure': 0, 
 u'canonical_ids': 1, 
 u'success': 1, 
 u'multicast_id': 4739141336251800642,
 u'results':
          [
           {
             u'registration_id': u'<reg-id>',
             u'message_id': u'0:1506410197124608%1e7d6f91f9fd7ecd'
           }
          ]
}
```

Comment: First thing first, change to Firebase Notification as GCM will phased out. Second, have you implemented GCM Service on your application?

Comment: Yes, I have implemented GCM service.  Though the success value is always 1, the notification is received on the device very few number of times. You can say 1 in 100 tries. Not getting the reason for this. 

And will look into FCM as well.